next.js on plesk with custom server.js not serves /_next requests
i have a server.js for next 14, it works in my machine with node server.js command but on plesk obsidian not serves requests starts with "/_next", basically it must serves .next folder with that but i got 404 error for thease static chunks and csses?!
this is my domain,
ketabhasti
this is my server.js:
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const dev = false;
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const hostname = "localhost";
const nextApp = next({ dir: ".", dev, hostname });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
try {
  nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    // Default catch-all renders Next app
    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
      nextHandler(req, res, parsedUrl);
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

i even tried to add thease lines but didnt worked:
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.use('/_next', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.next')))

my pckage.json:
{
  "name": "hasti-book",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./env/.env.development next dev",
    "build": "env-cmd -f ./env/.env.production next build",
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./env/.env.production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ducanh2912/next-pwa": "^10.2.7",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "typescript": "^5",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0"
  }
}


my guess is my document root, i must change it to .next folder maybe it helps, but righ now dont have permission to do it
